# SQL how to pivot the whole table on the top left cell

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

After googling it for a while, I have figured that I cannot use "pivot" as it is not available on Redshift but I thought that maybe there are geniuses around here that might be able to help me out on this one.

I would like to get the whole result table to pivot on the top left cell.

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT pid,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colA = 'true' THEN id ELSE NULL END) as "cA",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colB = 'true' THEN id ELSE NULL END) as "cB",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colC = 'true' THEN id ELSE NULL END) as "cC",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colD = 'true' THEN id ELSE NULL END) as "cD",
FROM Data1.Table1 
WHERE date1 >= date(getdate()-7) and pid IS NOT NULL
group by pid
```

and it gives me this table

```
pid cA  cB  cC  cD
r1  A1  B1  C1  D1
r2  A2  B2  C2  D2
r3  A3  B3  C3  D3
r4  A4  B4  C4  D4
```

How do I pivot it so that I get a table that looks like this:

```
pid r1  r2  r3  r4
cA  A1  A2  A3  A4
cB  B1  B2  B3  B4
cC  C1  C2  C3  C4
cD  D1  D2  D3  D4
```

In reality, the original table as many more columns than this example and is not easy to read. That is why I would like to pivot it and make it mostly vertical.

Is it possible to do so?

---

As requested, here is a "sample" of the data and what my current query gives me from the sample.

Sample

```
id      date1       pid cA      cB      cC      cD
1000    9/6/2017    r1  true    false   true    false
1001    9/7/2017    r1  false   true    true    true
1001    9/5/2017    r3  true    false   true    false
1002    9/7/2017    r2  true    true    true    false
1003    9/1/2017    r4  false   false   false   true
1004    8/24/2017   r3  true    false   true    false
1002    9/7/2017    r2  false   false   true    false
```

Query result

```
pid cA  cB  cC  cD
r1  1   1   2   1
r2  1   1   2   1
r3  2   0   2   0
r4  0   0   0   0
```

Wanted result

```
pid r1  r2  r3  r4
cA  1   1   2   0
cB  1   1   0   0
cC  2   2   2   0
cD  1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Can you post sample data from your table?

Comment: I cannot post actual sample of the data as it is sensitive but I made a sample that fits the data and what I get from the data right with my current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL to pivot it the way you want.

```
select 'cA' as pid
    , count(distinct case when ca is true and pid = 'r1' then id else null end) as r1
    , count(distinct case when ca is true and pid = 'r2' then id else null end) as r2
    , count(distinct case when ca is true and pid = 'r3' then id else null end) as r3
    , count(distinct case when ca is true and pid = 'r4' then id else null end) as r4
from table1
group by 1

union all

select 'cB' as pid
    , count(distinct case when cb is true and pid = 'r1' then id else null end) as r1
    , count(distinct case when cb is true and pid = 'r2' then id else null end) as r2
    , count(distinct case when cb is true and pid = 'r3' then id else null end) as r3
    , count(distinct case when cb is true and pid = 'r4' then id else null end) as r4
from table1
group by 1

union all

select 'cC' as pid
    , count(distinct case when cc is true and pid = 'r1' then id else null end) as r1
    , count(distinct case when cc is true and pid = 'r2' then id else null end) as r2
    , count(distinct case when cc is true and pid = 'r3' then id else null end) as r3
    , count(distinct case when cc is true and pid = 'r4' then id else null end) as r4
from table1
group by 1

union all

select 'cD' as pid
    , count(distinct case when cd is true and pid = 'r1' then id else null end) as r1
    , count(distinct case when cd is true and pid = 'r2' then id else null end) as r2
    , count(distinct case when cd is true and pid = 'r3' then id else null end) as r3
    , count(distinct case when cd is true and pid = 'r4' then id else null end) as r4
from table1
group by 1

order by 1
```

Feel free to add the WHERE clause as necessary.

Keep in mind that if there are more pids (r5,r6 ,etc), they need to be manually added. It's not very efficient but I don't think there is another way in Redshift.

Comment: It worked but the "Group by" is adding redundant rows so I removed it and I didn't use the "Order by" as the order is already given with each "Select"

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

I have used pure pivot conversion here:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table ( ids INT,A NVARCHAR(5),B NVARCHAR(5),C NVARCHAR(5),D NVARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (1,'A1','B1','C1','D1'), (2,'A2','B2','C2','D2'), (3,'A3','B3','C3','D3'),(4,'A4','B4','C4','D4'),(5,'A5','B5','C5','D5')
SELECT * FROM temp_table

DECLARE @temp_table_columns TABLE (id INT,col NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @result_val TABLE(id INT,value NVARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @temp_table_columns SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION id,COLUMN_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'temp_table'
DECLARE @initial_value NVARCHAR(MAX)='',@starter INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @temp_table_columns),@initial INT = 0
WHILE(@initial<@starter)
BEGIN
DECLARE @rower NVARCHAR(20) = (SELECT col FROM @temp_table_columns WHERE id=@initial+1)
INSERT INTO @result_val EXEC ('SELECT '''+@initial+''', '+@rower+' FROM temp_table')
SET @initial_value = @initial_value + 
' UNION SELECT '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@initial)+' [id],'''+@rower+''' '+@rower +(SELECT ', '''+value+''' ['+value+']' 
FROM @result_val WHERE id=@initial FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @initial=@initial+1
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='temp_table') DROP TABLE temp_table
SET @initial_value = 'SELECT * INTO temp_table FROM (' + SUBSTRING(@initial_value,8,LEN(@initial_value)) + ' ) A WHERE id<>0'
EXEC (@initial_value)
ALTER TABLE temp_table DROP COLUMN [id]
SELECT * FROM temp_table
```

You can modify it accordingly. :)

Comment: your solution seems to add values (A1, A2, A3...) to the table where my query grabs the data from a table. Am I wrong?
If I am wrong, I get an error on the first INSERT
Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "INSERT" Position: 99

Comment: This script is in T-SQL for SQL Server - it won't work on Amazon Redshift.